# Gitlab-Runner: concurrent runner crashes due to cache problems

Tags: gitlab, gitlab-ci-runner

I try to get a bunch of concurrent Gitlab runners running. While it works fine with serial running runners (concurrency = 1), it always fails for more than one.

I tried three single runners with this configuration:

```
concurrent = 3
check_interval = 1

[session_server]
  session_timeout = 1800

[[runners]]
  limit = 1
  name = "python3_0x01"
  url = "..."
  token = "..."
  executor = "docker"
  [runners.custom_build_dir]
  [runners.cache]
    [runners.cache.s3]
    [runners.cache.gcs]
    [runners.cache.azure]
  [runners.docker]
    tls_verify = false
    image = "python:3"
    privileged = false
    disable_entrypoint_overwrite = false
    oom_kill_disable = false
    disable_cache = false
    volumes = ["/cache"]
    shm_size = 0

[[runners]]
  limit = 1
  name = "python3_0x02"
  url = "..."
  token = "..."
  executor = "docker"
  [runners.custom_build_dir]
  [runners.cache]
    [runners.cache.s3]
    [runners.cache.gcs]
    [runners.cache.azure]
  [runners.docker]
    tls_verify = false
    image = "python:3"
    privileged = false
    disable_entrypoint_overwrite = false
    oom_kill_disable = false
    disable_cache = false
    volumes = ["/cache"]
    shm_size = 0

[[runners]]
  limit = 1
  name = "python3_0x03"
  url = "..."
  token = "..."
  executor = "docker"
  [runners.custom_build_dir]
  [runners.cache]
    [runners.cache.s3]
    [runners.cache.gcs]
    [runners.cache.azure]
  [runners.docker]
    tls_verify = false
    image = "python:3"
    privileged = false
    disable_entrypoint_overwrite = false
    oom_kill_disable = false
    disable_cache = false
    volumes = ["/cache"]
    shm_size = 0
```

and a one runner configuration

```
concurrent = 3
check_interval = 1

[session_server]
  session_timeout = 1800

[[runners]]
  limit = 3
  name = "python3_0x01"
  url = "..."
  token = "..."
  executor = "docker"
  [runners.custom_build_dir]
  [runners.cache]
    [runners.cache.s3]
    [runners.cache.gcs]
    [runners.cache.azure]
  [runners.docker]
    tls_verify = false
    image = "python:3"
    privileged = false
    disable_entrypoint_overwrite = false
    oom_kill_disable = false
    disable_cache = false
    volumes = ["/cache"]
    shm_size = 0
```

and also with no cache (the toml settings above are default from `gitlab-runner register`)

```
concurrent = 3
check_interval = 1

[session_server]
  session_timeout = 1800

[[runners]]
  limit = 3
  name = "python3_0x01"
  url = "..."
  token = "..."
  executor = "docker"
  [runners.custom_build_dir]
  [runners.docker]
    tls_verify = false
    image = "python:3"
    privileged = false
    disable_entrypoint_overwrite = false
    oom_kill_disable = false
    disable_cache = true
    shm_size = 0
```

But then executing a pipe with a bunch of jobs, the jobs crashes with something like this:

```sh
Running with gitlab-runner 14.4.0 (4b9e985a)
  on python3_0x01 ...
Preparing the "docker" executor
00:11
Using Docker executor with image python:3.8 ...
ERROR: Preparation failed: creating cache volume: set volume permissions: running permission container "9786fd6f223d03b159d6290106b76c6e525d172a7a1e5e805aaaf5b61c08548c" for volume "runner-dhj3akuj-project-15-concurrent-0-cache-c33bcaa1fd2c77edfc3893b41966cea8": starting permission container: Error response from daemon: OCI runtime create failed: container_linux.go:380: starting container process caused: process_linux.go:545: container init caused: Running hook #0:: error running hook: exit status 2, stdout: , stderr: runtime/cgo: pthread_create failed: Resource temporarily unavailable
runtime/cgo: pthread_create failed: Resource temporarily unavailable
SIGABRT: abort
PC=0x7f746866418b m=0 sigcode=18446744073709551610
goroutine 0 [idle]:
runtime: unknown pc 0x7f746866418b
stack: frame={sp:0x7ffd4ff18600, fp:0x0} stack=[0x7ffd4f719cd0,0x7ffd4ff18d10)
00007ffd4ff18500:  000055d84b7769a0  00007f7400000002 
00007ffd4ff18510:  0000000000000000  00007ffd4ff18a20 
00007ffd4ff18520:  000055d8ffffffff  000000004ad630bb 
00007ffd4ff18530:  0000000000000000  000055d8481c7f00 <runtime.goexit+0> 
00007ffd4ff18540:  00007ffd4ff18588  00007ffd4ff1857c 
00007ffd4ff18550:  0000000000000001  000055d84ad630bd 
00007ffd4ff18560:  000000000049ae13  000000000049ae13 
00007ffd4ff18570:  0000000000000000  0000000000000000 
00007ffd4ff18580:  000055d84b7769a0  000055d84b2f5ce0 
00007ffd4ff18590:  00007ffd4ff18650  000055d8481a7748 <runtime.adjustframe+136> 
00007ffd4ff185a0:  00007ffd4ff18918  00007ffd4ff18a20 
00007ffd4ff185b0:  00007ffd4ff18a01  000055d800000000 
00007ffd4ff185c0:  0000000000000000  0000000000000000 
00007ffd4ff185d0:  0000000000000000  0000000000000000 
00007ffd4ff185e0:  0000000000000000  0000000000000000 
00007ffd4ff185f0:  000055d84b7769a0  00000000000232db 
00007ffd4ff18600: <0000000000000000  00007ffd4ff18780 
00007ffd4ff18610:  000055d84a740e01  0000000000000000 
00007ffd4ff18620:  000055d84b7769a0  000055d84b2f5ce0 
00007ffd4ff18630:  0000000000000000  0000000000000000 
00007ffd4ff18640:  0000000000000000  0000000000000000 
00007ffd4ff18650:  00007ffd4ff18970  000055d8481b5655 <runtime.gentraceback+4405> 
00007ffd4ff18660:  00007ffd4ff18918  00007ffd4ff18a08 
00007ffd4ff18670:  000055d8481c7f01 <runtime.goexit+1>  00007ffd4ff18780 
00007ffd4ff18680:  fffffffe7fffffff  ffffffffffffffff 
00007ffd4ff18690:  ffffffffffffffff  ffffffffffffffff 
00007ffd4ff186a0:  ffffffffffffffff  ffffffffffffffff 
00007ffd4ff186b0:  ffffffffffffffff  ffffffffffffffff 
00007ffd4ff186c0:  ffffffffffffffff  ffffffffffffffff 
00007ffd4ff186d0:  ffffffffffffffff  ffffffffffffffff 
00007ffd4ff186e0:  ffffffffffffffff  ffffffffffffffff 
00007ffd4ff186f0:  ffffffffffffffff  ffffffffffffffff 
runtime: unknown pc 0x7f746866418b
stack: frame={sp:0x7ffd4ff18600, fp:0x0} stack=[0x7ffd4f719cd0,0x7ffd4ff18d10)
00007ffd4ff18500:  000055d84b7769a0  00007f7400000002 
00007ffd4ff18510:  0000000000000000  00007ffd4ff18a20 
00007ffd4ff18520:  000055d8ffffffff  000000004ad630bb 
00007ffd4ff18530:  0000000000000000  000055d8481c7f00 <runtime.goexit+0> 
00007ffd4ff18540:  00007ffd4ff18588  00007ffd4ff1857c 
00007ffd4ff18550:  0000000000000001  000055d84ad630bd 
00007ffd4ff18560:  000000000049ae13  000000000049ae13 
00007ffd4ff18570:  0000000000000000  0000000000000000 
00007ffd4ff18580:  000055d84b7769a0  000055d84b2f5ce0 
00007ffd4ff18590:  00007ffd4ff18650  000055d8481a7748 <runtime.adjustframe+136> 
00007ffd4ff185a0:  00007ffd4ff18918  00007ffd4ff18a20 
00007ffd4ff185b0:  00007ffd4ff18a01  000055d800000000 
00007ffd4ff185c0:  0000000000000000  0000000000000000 
00007ffd4ff185d0:  0000000000000000  0000000000000000 
00007ffd4ff185e0:  0000000000000000  0000000000000000 
00007ffd4ff185f0:  000055d84b7769a0  00000000000232db 
00007ffd4ff18600: <0000000000000000  00007ffd4ff18780 
00007ffd4ff18610:  000055d84a740e01  0000000000000000 
00007ffd4ff18620:  000055d84b7769a0  000055d84b2f5ce0 
00007ffd4ff18630:  0000000000000000  0000000000000000 
00007ffd4ff18640:  0000000000000000  0000000000000000 
00007ffd4ff18650:  00007ffd4ff18970  000055d8481b5655 <runtime.gentraceback+4405> 
00007ffd4ff18660:  00007ffd4ff18918  00007ffd4ff18a08 
00007ffd4ff18670:  000055d8481c7f01 <runtime.goexit+1>  00007ffd4ff18780 
00007ffd4ff18680:  fffffffe7fffffff  ffffffffffffffff 
00007ffd4ff18690:  ffffffffffffffff  ffffffffffffffff 
00007ffd4ff186a0:  ffffffffffffffff  ffffffffffffffff 
00007ffd4ff186b0:  ffffffffffffffff  ffffffffffffffff 
00007ffd4ff186c0:  ffffffffffffffff  ffffffffffffffff 
00007ffd4ff186d0:  ffffffffffffffff  ffffffffffffffff 
00007ffd4ff186e0:  ffffffffffffffff  ffffffffffffffff 
00007ffd4ff186f0:  ffffffffffffffff  ffffffffffffffff 
goroutine 1 [runnable, locked to thread]:
github.com/docker/docker/vendor/github.com/prometheus/client_golang/prometheus.(*Registry).Register(0xc00014a870, 0x55d84a77c648, 0xc00014a8c0, 0x0, 0x0)
    /go/src/github.com/docker/docker/vendor/github.com/prometheus/client_golang/prometheus/registry.go:285 +0x20f
github.com/docker/docker/vendor/github.com/prometheus/client_golang/prometheus.(*Registry).MustRegister(0xc00014a870, 0xc0001118c0, 0x1, 0x1)
    /go/src/github.com/docker/docker/vendor/github.com/prometheus/client_golang/prometheus/registry.go:399 +0x7a
github.com/docker/docker/vendor/github.com/prometheus/client_golang/prometheus.MustRegister(...)
    /go/src/github.com/docker/docker/vendor/github.com/prometheus/client_golang/prometheus/registry.go:177
github.com/docker/docker/vendor/github.com/prometheus/client_golang/prometheus.init.0()
    /go/src/github.com/docker/docker/vendor/github.com/prometheus/client_golang/prometheus/registry.go:61 +0xb7
rax    0x0
rbx    0x7f74682488c0
rcx    0xffffffffffffffff
rdx    0x0
rdi    0x2
rsi    0x7ffd4ff18600
rbp    0x7ffd4ff18950
rsp    0x7ffd4ff18600
r8     0x0
r9     0x7ffd4ff18600
r10    0x8
r11    0x246
r12    0x55d84a10eea5
r13    0x7ffd4ff18a10
r14    0x55d84a0e0c46
r15    0x0
rip    0x7f746866418b
rflags 0x246
cs     0x33
fs     0x0
gs     0x0: unknown (linux_set.go:105:0s)
Will be retried in 3s ...
```

or with this error

```
Running with gitlab-runner 14.4.0 (4b9e985a)
  on python3_0x03 136fu3hd
Preparing the "docker" executor
00:10
Using Docker executor with image python:3.8 ...
ERROR: Preparation failed: adding cache volume: set volume permissions: running permission container "0cc90426476f4550776dfa4807ed7c4889fccf61107733622f9fdd8294655601" for volume "runner-136fu3hd-project-15-concurrent-0-cache-3c3f060a0374fc8bc39395164f415a70": starting permission container: Error response from daemon: : fork/exec /usr/bin/containerd-shim-runc-v2: resource temporarily unavailable: unknown (linux_set.go:105:0s)
Will be retried in 3s ...
```

How can that be resolved?

---

```
$ docker info
Client:
 Context:    default
 Debug Mode: false
 Plugins:
  app: Docker App (Docker Inc., v0.9.1-beta3)
  buildx: Build with BuildKit (Docker Inc., v0.6.3-docker)
  scan: Docker Scan (Docker Inc., v0.9.0)

Server:
 Containers: 3
  Running: 3
  Paused: 0
  Stopped: 0
 Images: 5
 Server Version: 20.10.10
 Storage Driver: overlay2
  Backing Filesystem: extfs
  Supports d_type: true
  Native Overlay Diff: true
  userxattr: false
 Logging Driver: json-file
 Cgroup Driver: cgroupfs
 Cgroup Version: 1
 Plugins:
  Volume: local
  Network: bridge host ipvlan macvlan null overlay
  Log: awslogs fluentd gcplogs gelf journald json-file local logentries splunk syslog
 Swarm: inactive
 Runtimes: runc io.containerd.runc.v2 io.containerd.runtime.v1.linux
 Default Runtime: runc
 Init Binary: docker-init
 containerd version: 5b46e404f6b9f661a205e28d59c982d3634148f8
 runc version: v1.0.2-0-g52b36a2
 init version: de40ad0
 Security Options:
  seccomp
   Profile: default
 Kernel Version: 4.15.0
 Operating System: Ubuntu 20.04.3 LTS
 OSType: linux
 Architecture: x86_64
 CPUs: 6
 Total Memory: 16GiB
 Name: myserver.net
 ID: ....
 Docker Root Dir: /var/lib/docker
 Debug Mode: false
 Registry: https://index.docker.io/v1/
 Labels:
 Experimental: false
 Insecure Registries:
  127.0.0.0/8
 Live Restore Enabled: false

WARNING: bridge-nf-call-iptables is disabled
WARNING: bridge-nf-call-ip6tables is disabled
```

and

```sh
$ sudo gitlab-runner health-check
Runtime platform                                    arch=amd64 os=linux pid=1642727 revision=4b9e985a version=14.4.0
FATAL: No HOST or PORT found
```

```sh
$ sudo gitlab-runner list
Runtime platform                                    arch=amd64 os=linux pid=1643028 revision=4b9e985a version=14.4.0
Listing configured runners                          ConfigFile=/etc/gitlab-runner/config.toml
ubuntu                                              Executor=docker Token=go-AiPPD1QhP4vr7QNtA URL=https://myserver.net
ubuntu_0x01                                         Executor=docker Token=6xJyHoqvUeuzCxDhUYxy URL=http://<local-ip>
python38_0x01                                       Executor=docker Token=geQE63Dbfro2TL4KaaW7 URL=http://<local-ip>
```

Comment: What OS are you using? Can you show the output of `docker info` from the host?

Answer (score 0):

> Error response from daemon: : fork/exec /usr/bin/containerd-shim-runc-v2: resource temporarily unavailable: unknown

This means that the docker daemon was unable to create a process due to *resource temporarily unavailable* -- which may indicate you have got too many processes/containers running, preventing the fork.

Check that you don't have a bunch of rogue processes/containers running on this host and that the disk/partition used by docker is not full.

This may also happen if you tried to start the gitlab runner while another instance of the runner was already running using the same config file.